# Java regex matches diacritics for the Latin corresponding characters

Tags: java, regex, nlp, diacritics

I am trying to use a regex such as `[ăâîșțĂÂÎȘȚ]` to match for Romanian alphabet diacritics(ISO 8859-16/Windows-1250). The problem is that the regex would also match the regex for a,i,s,t,A,I,S,T(the Latin alphabet corresponding characters for the above mentioned diacritics) and I don't want this.
I didn't try to compare strings character by character because of performance time.

Is there anyway I can make the regex match exactly for these characters?

Comment: What regex engine/language are you using? This shouldn't happen, see [here](https://regex101.com/r/3W8Hky/1).

Comment: It [does not seem true](http://ideone.com/tzTjjv). Could you please provide a Java demo showing the behavior you described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your regex exists as literal rendered text, it has already been combined
and should exist as a different code point.

```
000074    t    LATIN SMALL LETTER T
+
000326    ̦    COMBINING COMMA BELOW
=
00021B    ț    LATIN SMALL LETTER T WITH COMMA BELOW
```

Just incase, you should use a hex codepoint to represent them ie. *`u\021B`*

Is it possible the Java engine could be stripping the combining character off of the  regex?
Where x21B becomes x74? Might be that.

Meanwhile if you expect the letters in the source are not rendered, you could
use a regex like `\p{Script=Latin}\p{Block=Combining_Diacritical_Marks}`
to get those.

***updated info :***
While searching around for a defacto solution, I came across this Java info
from  http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html.

> In Java, the regex token \uFFFF only matches the specified 
>       code point, even when you turned on canonical equivalence. 
>       However, the same syntax \uFFFF is also used to insert 
>       Unicode characters into literal strings in the Java source 
>       code. Pattern.compile("\u00E0") will match both the 
>       single-code-point and double-code-point encodings of à, 
>       while Pattern.compile("\u00E0") matches only the 
>       single-code-point version. Remember that when writing a 
>       regex as a Java string literal, backslashes must be escaped.
>       The former Java code compiles the regex à, while the latter 
>       compiles \u00E0. Depending on what you're doing, the 
>       difference may be significant.

So, by entering a duality literal inside a class, it looks like `Pattern.compile("[à]")`
will actually match

```
000061    a    LATIN SMALL LETTER A
or
000300    ̀    COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT
or
0000E0    à    LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH GRAVE
```

This smacks of the same problem when putting surrogate pairs inside classes.
There is a solution.

Avoid entering those literals inside of a class.
Instead, put them as a series of alternations
`(?:à|_|_|_)`

Doing this forces it to match either

```
000061    a    LATIN SMALL LETTER A
000300    ̀    COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT
```

*or*

```
0000E0    à    LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH GRAVE
```

It won't match `a` independent of the *grave* like you see now.

Note - *If you just use a "[\\u00E0]" you'd miss the `a + grave`.*
which is valid.

Comment: There are many ways an editor could write out such characters, so using the unicode escape sequences as you suggest, as well as normalising the input string (see Normaliser - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html and tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/normalizerapi.html) is probably wise to guarantee consistent behaviour across various encodings of the same logical character strings.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is happening because those characters are being treated as two Unicode code points. I would recommend trying to specifically match the code points using syntax like \uFFFF where FFFF is the code point. The exact syntax will depend on the regex implementation you are using.

Keep in mind that Unicode characters can be encoded as single code points or as multiple, so you'll want to account for that. Example: à encoded as U+0061 U+0300 and also U+00E0.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in Unicode one has two alternatives.

```
'\u0061'    'a'   LATIN SMALL LETTER A
'\u0300'     ̀     COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT
```

or

```
'\u00E0'    'à'   LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH GRAVE
```

There is a [`Normalizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) that can "normalize" to either form (and deal with ligatures):

```
String regex = "(?u)[ăâîșțĂÂÎȘȚ]";
regex = Normalizer.normalize(regex, Form.NFC); // Composed form
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
```

Using "(?u)" or a flag with Pattern.compile with UNICODE flag might already solve the problem. But using the Unicode variant without separate latin (`'a'`) will certainly do.

The normalizer should especially be applied on the searched-through string.